# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() when set Listadapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When I called my webservice,I can retrieve/extract data from my webservice. The scenario is I want to `setListAdapter()` 
for asyntask in postexcute method but it gives me error as  `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion`. please help me to figure out this issue.

```
public class ViewStatusActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private List<QueryRowItem> queryRowItemList;
List<String> QueryDetailsList;
String str_mob;

ViewStatusAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

ListView listview;

List<String> list;


// url to create new product
    private static String url_make_query = "http://testsyifs.com/QuerybookScripts/get_result_by_mobile.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_status);


    Intent intent=getIntent();
    str_mob=intent.getStringExtra("mobNo");
    Log.d("MOBILE NUMBER", str_mob);
    listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    getPendingList();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_status, menu);
    return true;
}

public void getPendingList()
{
    //final String option=MainActivity.strStatus;
    //queryRowItemList = new ArrayList<QueryRowItem>();     
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>()
    {
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewStatusActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Loading....");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        };

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            String response = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();            
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sender_mobile_no",str_mob));

            if (Common.isInternetConnected(ViewStatusActivity.this))
            {
                try 
                {
                    response = Common.httpPost(url_make_query, nameValuePairs, new String[] {});
                    Log.v(Common.TAG, "*****JSON Response ******:=> " + response);                      
                    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);  

                    Log.v(Common.TAG, "JSON Length= "+jsonarray.length());                      

                    for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject item = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // Get values from JSON Array. 
                        int intQueryId=item.getInt("query_id");
                        String strSenderMobileNo=item.getString("sender_mobile_no");
                        String strSenderName=item.getString("sender_name");
                        String strQueryString=item.getString("query_string");
                        String strActionTaken=item.getString("action_taken");                           
                        String strStatus=item.getString("status");
                        String strQueryDate=item.getString("query_date");                           
                        String strActionDate=item.getString("action_date");

                        map.put("query_string",strQueryString);
                        map.put("status", strStatus);
                        arraylist.add(map);

                    }                                                                   
                } 
                catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //groupMember.setSynced_with_server(StaticMembers.ZERO);                    
                return "NO_NETWORK";
            }
            return response;
        };

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {               
            if (result != null)
            {
                if(!result.equals("NO_NETWORK"))
                {                           
                    //groupMember.setSynced_with_server(StaticMembers.ONE);                         
                }                       


                adapter = new ViewStatusAdapter(ViewStatusActivity.this, arraylist);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
            dismissDialog();
        }
    }.execute(null, null);
}

//
// Dismiss progress bar.
//
public void dismissDialog() 
{
    try 
    {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) 
        {
            try 
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e(Common.TAG, "Error while dismissing dialog.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

Comment: please post logcat msgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
```

to

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```